# How can I pass a Textboxes value to my Ajax.ActionLink?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax, actionlink

In my ASP.NET MVC application I want a user to add a value into a textbox and then press my Ajax.ActionLink.  I want to do something like this:

Ajax.ActionLink("Go", "Action", "Controller", new { value = textbox1.value })

Or how else can I get this textbox value back to my action? Jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may run action using AJAX [$.get](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get) method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#t").change(function()
        {
            RunAction();
        });

        RunAction();
    });

    function RunAction()
    {
        var action = '<%= Url.Action("Action", "Controller") %>';
        var data = $("#t").serialize();
        $.get(action, data);
    }

</script>

<input type="text" id="t" />
```

Comment: That almost gets me there...but this does not create a AJAX call, but rather just a standard POST.

Comment: I have changed code to make AJAX call. In case of need look also jQuery documentation to learn how to process returned ActionResult.

Comment: Answer to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458055/jquery-mvc-user-controls) could also be useful.

Comment: ofcoarse, I think I will rather use the jquery .load method however

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot Alexander!  Thank you for putting me on the right path.  I did not try you latest code, but I was able to get your previous code working.  Here is the working code.  I'm sure this is all kludgy, but perhaps someone out there can show me a more elegant solution:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#myVal").change(function() {
                        changeActionURL();
                    });
                    changeActionURL();
                });
            function changeActionURL() {
                var url = '<%= new UrlHelper(ViewContext.RequestContext).Action("Action", "Controller") %>' + '?dup=' + $("#myVal").val();
                $("#u").attr('href', url);
            }
            </script>

            <a id="u" href="" onclick="Sys.Mvc.AsyncHyperlink.handleClick(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event), { insertionMode: Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace, updateTargetId: 'HellaYeah' });">Report Dupe</a>

        </p>
        <div id="response">not done</div>
```

My solution as you can see is just to hard code the LINK instead of trying to use the ASP.NET AJAX helper class.

Answer (score 1):

this is how you retrieve the value from your textbox in JQuery

```
var input =  $('input[name=txt_MyTextBox]').val()
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm trying to get that data back to my server code...to me that means I need to pass the data back to the server via JSON or some other method.  I'm HOPING asp.net has some tricky method to grab the data without having to rely on javascipt.

Comment: Since the textbox and what is in it is on the client side, you will need to rely on client side scripting to make this happen.  The exception is if instead of doing the Ajax call, you submit the form, then MVC process it on the server side for you.

Answer (score 0):

replace $.get(action, data); 
with $("#yourTargetId").load(action, data);
you get a ajax as in the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#t").change(function()
        {
            RunAction();
        });

        RunAction();
    });

    function RunAction()
    {
        var action = '<%= Url.Action("Action", "Controller") %>';
        var data = $("#t").serialize();
        $("#yourTargetId").load(action, data);
    }

</script>

<input type="text" id="t" />
```